# ava.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: dalvik.system.VMRuntime.pauseGc:(Ljava/lang/String;)I

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection

I run my android application and all the sudden it crashes on init

The problem is that i cannot see my code line in the stack trace.

What does this error mean?

```
08-20 17:25:59.024: E/(30678): Device driver API match
08-20 17:25:59.024: E/(30678): Device driver API version: 23
08-20 17:25:59.024: E/(30678): User space API version: 23 
08-20 17:25:59.024: E/(30678): mali: REVISION=Linux-r3p2-01rel3 BUILD_DATE=Fri Mar 21 13:52:50 KST 2014 
08-20 17:26:01.674: E/ActivityThread(30678): Pause GC
08-20 17:26:01.674: E/ActivityThread(30678): java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-20 17:26:01.674: E/ActivityThread(30678):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-20 17:26:01.674: E/ActivityThread(30678):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-20 17:26:01.674: E/ActivityThread(30678):    at android.app.ActivityThread.pauseGC(ActivityThread.java:5525)
08-20 17:26:01.674: E/ActivityThread(30678):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2324)
08-20 17:26:01.674: E/ActivityThread(30678):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
08-20 17:26:01.674: E/ActivityThread(30678):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
08-20 17:26:01.674: E/ActivityThread(30678):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
08-20 17:26:01.674: E/ActivityThread(30678):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-20 17:26:01.674: E/ActivityThread(30678):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
08-20 17:26:01.674: E/ActivityThread(30678):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
08-20 17:26:01.674: E/ActivityThread(30678):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-20 17:26:01.674: E/ActivityThread(30678):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-20 17:26:01.674: E/ActivityThread(30678):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
08-20 17:26:01.674: E/ActivityThread(30678):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
08-20 17:26:01.674: E/ActivityThread(30678):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-20 17:26:01.674: E/ActivityThread(30678): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: dalvik.system.VMRuntime.pauseGc:(Ljava/lang/String;)I
08-20 17:26:01.674: E/ActivityThread(30678):    at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.pauseGc(Native Method)
08-20 17:26:01.674: E/ActivityThread(30678):    ... 15 more
```

Comment: did you solve this problem? I also have the same problem

Comment: have you find any solution for the problem

Comment: what platform are you running on?